# web services for iOS application is very slow

Tags: ios, web-services

I am using hosted web services in ovh.com. The problem is its slow and unstable.Is any good service provider to hosting web services which is faster and efficient.I Just want to post the images and user registration data.

Comment: i need info about good service provider

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik he is not asking for the libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several persons are available, but in before u choose  u need to follow the package, 24 X 7 support,data secure,  storage or memory, etc..

1. http://www.1and1.com/cheap-web-hosting
2. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/business-hosting
3. http://www.ixwebhosting.com
4. http://www.verio.com/about/value/global-ip-network/
5. http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/
6. http://www.findwebhosts.com
7. https://www.ipage.com/ipage/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your budget. Just type 'best web hosting' on the google & u'll get lots of web-sites siting good hosting providers.
Try this: [Best 10 Web Hosting 2014 - Top10BestWebsiteHosting.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=best%20web-hostings&oq=best%20web-hostings&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6849j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)
Remember, this also depends on your location. You should choose the provider that suits most your target audience of your web-services. Good Luck!